# What are the substitutes for kitchen wall tiles above a kitchen counter?

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters, ceramic-tile, granite, marble

Can anyone let me know what are the various options that we can use in place of ceramic wall tiles in kitchen (just above the kitchen counter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean as a backsplash?

Just about any material can be used:  ceramic, glass, vinyl, ABS, wood, aluminum, steel, contact paper, etc.  See [this gallery](https://www.google.com/search?q=backsplash%20photo&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=QE-4U8SUIdCDogS6uoHICQ&ved=0CBwQsAQ&biw=1760&bih=988) for many ideas.

While most of them are ceramic tile, which is the current fashion, look carefully and you'll see vinyls which look metallic.  [Here](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Traditional-1-18-in-x-24-in-PVC-Decorative-Backsplash-Panel-in-Cross-Hatch-Silver-B50-21/100521695) is Home Depot's version of that.  We are considering that for behind the range.

Comment: If you are not too subject to swings of fashion, stainless steel (the real thing, not vinyl that looks like it) is VERY functional. Fireproof and easy to clean. Any countertop material can also be used for backsplash....

Answer (score 2):

To expand on wallyk's answer: nearly anything.

It's really entirely up to you. The main two things to consider are maintainability (how easy is it to keep clean) and aesthetics (what do you like?)

The range of options can include (but is not limited to):

- Tiles

  - Ceramic (as you mention)
  - glass
  - metal
  - stone
  - etc
- Metal

  - stainless steel
  - copper
  - etc
- countertop materials

  - stone (marble, granite, slate, soapstone, etc.)
  - laminates
  - etc
- etc

  - back painted glass panels
  - vinyl
  - rubber
  - mosaic
  - concrete/terrazzo
  - adhesive roll material (ie contact paper)
  - panelling
  - cork
  - (and perhaps most common) wallboard and paint

Answer (score 1):

If your counter did not come with a backsplash, you could have a small one (6 inches high or so) made to match the counter and then just paint above that.